# Metro Style Apps- MS Office libraries

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I was trying to read/write MS word documents in a metro style app (C#,xaml), but it seems that metro apps do not support Office libraries. Is it possible to achieve this in metro apps? Some work around? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a ASPOSE for Word: http://asposewords.codeplex.com/

It is a class library that enables your applications to perform a great range of document processing tasks. Aspose.Words supports DOC, DOCX, RTF, HTML, OpenDocument, PDF, XPS, EPUB and other formats. With Aspose.Words you can generate, modify, convert, render and print documents without utilizing Microsoft Word.

Comment: be aware that the CodePlex project contains **sample** code that exercises ASPOSE, which is a commercial product.  [From their site](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx), it appears the entry point in $999 for single developer use and deployment.  Also it's not clear that this product is supported for Windows 8 store apps.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to work something out by using the [SkyDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521), but I don't believe that this is currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) in CTP, but

```
Open XML SDK 2.5 CTP does not support “.NET APIs for Metro style apps”
```

There's no statement one way or the other on support at release.

Under the covers the Word document is all XML though and the [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240819.aspx) namespace is available - granted a lot more work than a convenient object model.